# Unable to use method toBuilder() (undefined)

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gwt, lombok

I'm trying to use **Lombok** in my **GWT** application.
I have added the dependency with **Gradle**.
There is no warnings or errors in the code when I use **@Builder(toBuilder = true)** or **.toBuilder().build()**.
But when I try to start the application, there is a compilation error :

*[ERROR] Line 222: The method toBuilder() is undefined for the type WorkAccidentDTO
[ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly.*

I just want to create a clone of an existing object (and since Object.clone() doesn't work with GWT, I'm trying to use Lombok).

I have tried with different versions of Lombok, it doesn't change anything.
The lombok plugin is installed, "Enable annotation processing" is enable.

Version : 
Lombok : 1.18.8 /
Gradle : 1.11 (I know, it's a bit old) /
IntelliJ : Ultimate, 2018.3.6

Below, what I'm trying to use...quite simple...

`@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class WorkAccidentDTO implements Serializable, Comparator<WorkAccidentDTO> {...}`

`final WorkAccidentDTO workAccidentDTO = instance.toBuilder().build();`

Thanks for your help

Comment: how did you declare lombok dependencies in the `build.gradle` file ?

Comment: compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'

Comment: How are you passing it to your GWT task? https://projectlombok.org/setup/gwt is the official Lombok steps to configure your JVM running GWT to use lombok, did you follow these instructions to change your gradle config to do this in the gwt task?

Comment: I don't really understand what they are speaking about :
_Edit your proj-debug and proj-compile batch scripts to add the following VM arguments_

ECJ, isn't it for Eclipse ?

Comment: I'm just trying to clone Object in fact. So, if there is another way of doing this (without Lombok), it's ok too. But it seems that external jar are not always welcome with GWT. And I would like to avoid copy constructors